# having trouble running the FLTK 1.3.3

Tags: user-interface, visual-studio-2013, header-files, fltk

I am using MS Visual Studio Professional (2013).
I have compiled the fltk 1.3 successfully and followed all the instructions given at this [link](https://bewuethr.github.io/installing-fltk-133-under-visual-studio/)

but i am still getting the error, that it cannot find the files

[image: error]

What do i need to change to make it work.
I followed this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6804275/fltk-in-msvc-needs-x11-headers) and did the same but it doesn't work either.

Comment: Did you do this step **Now copy (don’t move) the following from your fltk-1.3.3 folder: The complete FL directory to VC\include**

Answer (score 1):

What the error says is that the compiler can not find the FLTK include files.
You can solve it by going to project properties (right click on the project) then Configuration Properties --> C/C++.
Then add the path to the FLTK directory to list of "Additional Include Directories"

Comment: thank you though.
took me a log of time to complie the FLTK and then like do 100 different things to run it.